# regular expression for "def"

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression for "def"
it should work as following:

```
def h():
def f(a=1):
def g(a=-2):
def x(_sad,sda_,m=+3, n=-2):
```

cases it don't work:

```
def (m, x=y)
```

what I did:

```
^def\s\w+\((\w\,)*(\w+=?\+?\-?\d+\,)*(\w)*\):$
```

However, it doesn't pass the case "`def f(a=1):`" and "`def g(a=-2):`"

Where I did wrong??

My object here is to fulfill these cases:

```
def h():
def f(a=1):
def g(a=-2):
def x(_sad,sda_,m=+3, n=-2):
```

and not fulfill these cases:
    def (m, x=y)

Comment: What are you trying to capture? If you just want to check for the word `def`, what's wrong with doing a literal search, like `'def' in string`?

Comment: Use the `ast` module. Don't try and use a regex to do what a parser should be used to do...

Comment: Analyzing a statement is done with a `parser` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages).  It is usually done with a context-free grammar, not with regular expressions.

Comment: Parsing a `def` statement is likely going to be impossible for a regex, as the default parameter values can be any kind of expression. Python is not a regular language, so you need a more sophisticated set of tools to parse it.

Answer (score -2):

Just for fun

```
\s*def\s+[^\(]+\([^\)]*(?:(?:\([^\)]*?\))[^\)]*)*\):
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wH6cT2/1)

**Explanation:**
`^`: Start of string or start of line depending on multiline mode
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`\w`: "word character": ASCII letter, digit or underscore [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ2lG4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)

Input:

```
def h():
def f(a=1):
def g(a=-2):
def x(_sad,sda_,m=+3, n=-2):
def (m, x=y) 
def name(database_name):
    def name(name1, name2):
        def name(name1, attr=value):
    def name(name1, default='', length=default, **value):
    def name(name1, default='', length=(0, 999), **kwargs):
```

Match all except `def (m, x=y)`

Comment: There is often whitespace before `def`.

Comment: Then add `\s*` before `def`

Comment: And valid Python identifiers can include more than just ASCII.

Comment: A regular expression is simply not powerful enough to parse a python function definition